# How to add 'n' amount of odd integers?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to write a program that computes the sum of the first n positive odd integers.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to incorporate n into finding the sum. I already have a do/while loop to ensure I get a positive value when assigning n value. I know that I have to use a for loop but I'm not really sure how I would do that.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // open input stream
    String cleanUpStr;                      // clean kbd buffer
    int n;                                  // number
    int sum;                                // sum of numbers
    int cntr;                               // counter for loop

    cleanUpStr = "nothing yet";
    n = 0;
    sum = 0;
    cntr = 0;

    //prompt user for the value of n
    // use a loop to ensure a positive output
    do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the value of n");

        n = input.nextInt();
        cleanUpStr = input.nextLine();

        // print error if n is invalid
        if (n < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid n value of " + n + ", try again.");
        } // end if

    }while(n < 0);

    for(cntr = 0; cntr < n; ++cntr)
    {


    } // end for




} // end main
```

For example: if n = 5, then this should compute 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Stream` is good, but if you're a beginner a plain old `for` loop is your best friend.

```
public static int sumForOddNumbers(int total) {
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0, odd = 1; i < total; i++, odd += 2) {
        sum += odd;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The nice thing about this problem, is that you don't need to write a loop! The sum of the first n positive odd integers is the square of n (written throughout this post as n^2). This is how you express the sum in terms of n. So the following will suffice:

```
// Calculate the sum of first n positive odd integers by using the n^2 formula.
public static int sumOddIntegers(int n) {
    return n*n;
}
```

If you're set on using a loop, you can do the following by observing that the i-th positive odd integer can be calculated using the formula (2i-1):

```
// Calculate the sum of first n positive odd integers by adding each number iteratively in a loop.
public static int sumOddIntegers(int n) {
    int oddSum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        oddSum += (2*i - 1);
    }
    return oddSum;
}
```

To visualize this, consider the following examples:

```
n = 1 List: {1} S(n) = 1 = 1 = n^2
n = 2 List: {1, 3} S(n) = 1 + 3 = 4 = n^2
n = 3 List: {1, 3, 5} S(n) = 1 + 3 + 5 = 9 = n^2
n = 4 List: {1, 3, 5, 7} S(n) = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16 = n^2
n = 5 List: {1, 3, 5, 7, 9} S(n) = 1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25 = n^2
And so on...
```

Here is a proof by induction showing that the sum of the first n positive odd numbers is n^2. I'm new to Stack Overflow, so I hope my formatting is legible. If it can be improved, please feel free to suggest edits :) It seems like Stack Overflow doesn't support LaTeX style exponent and subscript formatting, so I did my best.

## Proof

P(n): The sum of the first n positive odd integers is n^2.

### Base Case

P(1): n = 1

The n = 1 case is trivial. The list of the first n positive odd integers is simply {1}. Therefore the sum of the first n positive odd integers is 1. Since 1 = n = n^2, the predicate P(1) holds true.

### Inductive Hypothesis

Assume that P(k) holds for any arbitrary positive integer k > 0.

### Inductive Step

Given P(k), we will prove that P(k+1) also holds true. In words, if the sum of the first k positive odd integers is k^2, then the sum of the first (k+1) positive odd integers is (k+1)^2.

As part of this proof, assume the following lemma.

Lemma 1: The nth positive odd integer can be expressed as 2n-1.

If P(k) holds, then the sum of the first k positive odd integers {a_1, ... a_k} is k^2 where the element a_k is expressed as 2k-1 (by Lemma 1). It follows that adding the (k+1)st positive odd integer, a_(k+1) to the list of the first k positive odd integers will produce a list of the first (k+1) positive odd integers as follows: {a_1, ... a_k, a_(k+1)}. Therefore, the sum of this list of the first (k+1) positive odd integers will be equal to the sum of the list of the first k positive odd integers plus the value of a_(k+1), the (k+1)st positive odd integer. By Lemma 1, the (k+1)st positive odd integer is expressed as 2(k+1)-1 = 2k+1.

Let S(k) = the sum of the first k positive odd integers. Therefore, S(k) = k^2. The above statements imply that

```
S(k+1) = S(k) + a_(k+1), adding the (k+1)st positive odd integer

S(k+1) = S(k) + (2(k+1)-1), by Lemma 1 

S(k+1) = S(k) + (2k+1)  

S(k+1) = k^2 + (2k+1), by inductive hypothesis

S(k+1) = k^2 + 2k + 1

S(k+1) = (k+1)^2, by factoring
```

We have therefore shown that if S(k) = k^2, then S(k+1) = (k+1)^2. This shows that P(k) -> P(k+1).

By induction, we have proved that P(n) holds for any positive integer n > 0.
The sum of the first n positive odd integers is therefore n^2. QED.

#### Proof of Lemma 1:

Here is a proof of this by induction.

P(n): The nth positive odd integer, a_n, can be expressed as 2n-1.

Base case: P(1): 1 is the first positive odd integer (case n = 1).

```
1 = 2(1)-1 = 1. 

Therefore, a_1 = 1 = 2n-1. Correct.
```

Inductive Hypothesis: Assume P(k) holds.

Inductive Step: If P(k) holds, then P(k+1) holds.

If P(k) holds, then the kth positive odd integer can be expressed as 2k-1. By addition, the next positive odd integer (the (k+1)st positive odd integer), would be (2k-1) + 2.

```
= (2k-1) + 2
= 2k-1 + 2
= 2k+2 - 1
= 2(k+1) -1
```

We have shown that P(k) -> P(k+1). Therefore, by induction, P(n) holds for all integers n > 0. QED.

Good luck! Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

Java stream API suggests quite clear solution:

```
IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 2)
     .limit(n)
     .sum();
```

More about `IntStream` by [link](https://www.deadcoderising.com/2015-05-19-java-8-replace-traditional-for-loops-with-intstreams/)

Comment: Without loop: n -> n*n

Comment: While correct, this answer does nothing to explain why this code works.

Answer (score 2):

While streams would be a great way to go about this if you were concerned with functional programming, just learning Java I would suggest the below.

```
int oddValue = 1; 
int answer = 0;  
for(cntr = 0; cntr < n; ++cntr)
    {
        //adds oddvalue to your answer
        answer += oddValue;
        //adds two to odd value (next odd)
        oddValue+=2;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous approaches to this problem.

The way you're thinking about it, yes, you can use a loop. Generally, you have a loop counter and some maximum.

The first observation to make is that odd numbers are written in the form `2k-1`. Such as k=3, `2 * 3 - 1 = 5`, i.e., 5 is the 3rd odd number.

Given this, you can write a loop for `k`, as follows:

```
for (int k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
  int oddNumber = 2 * k - 1; // the kth odd number
}
```

You can then sum these up.

Another way to do it is the way @Ruslan has shown, which uses a lambda expression to encode a similar idea. It walks over a list of integers, starting at 1 and stepping 2 each time: `1, 3, 5, 7, ...`. This can be done in a loop as well:

```
for (int oddNumber = 1; oddNumber <= (2*n - 1); oddNumber += 2) {
   // calculate a sum here
}
```

Notice that this `2*n - 1` expression came up again. We're counting odd numbers until we reach the nth one.

There are also ways to do this without loops, such as realizing the following pattern:

```
1 = 1
1 + 3 = 4
1 + 3 + 5 = 9
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 16
1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9 = 25
```

This means that the sum of the first `n` odd numbers is just `n^2`. No loops needed. (Proofs for this are available on your favourite math website.)